# How can we improve the GC performance for low latency system

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

Our java backend system is running with tomcat and jdk1.8, max jvm size is 24g, system latency becomes long, and cpu load is high, after we analyze GC logs, we found GC pause is long, attached are some snapshots in GCViewer.
How can we improve the GC performance?

[image: Chart]

[image: Event Details]

[image: Memory]

[image: Pause]

[image: Summary]

Comment: Have you tried anything? There is a huge amount of information online about how to tune the GC. It usually requires an methodical, incremental, approach. You can't just expect to dump some metrics here and for us to say "yeah, you forgot the -XXgoReallyFast flag"

Comment: Don’t you have any monitoring tool at hand that allows to copy the diagnostics *as text* instead of screenshots? Or just log files?

Comment: You're experiencing concurrent mode failures, you might want to bump the max heap size. Or you can try upgrading to java 12 and try one of the experimental low-pause collectors (shenandoah, ZGC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowledge of your application, here are some general thoughts:

- Your application seems to have a high amount of long-lived objects (only 9gb of the tenured generation get collected, 15gb remain), which cause your problems: While allocation speed determines the frequency of GC pauses it is the amount of living objects (that cannot be freed by GC) which determines the length of the GC pauses.
- One possible cause could be that your application acts as an in-memory database to some extent. That is, the objects are not needed all the time, but are not written to a database to retain fast in-memory access to them. In that case, you should store them off-heap (in memory not managed by the GC) or use an in-memory database, e.g. Redis. This way, they will be accessible with low latency but won't be considered by the GC because they won't be reclaimed anyway.
- Another possible solution might be to tune your GC settings: You could switch to G1, increase the size of your young generation or increase the promotion threshold; or a combination of those. Increasing the young generation and reducing promotion might lead to much less growth of the tenured generation and thus to less frequent major collections. Switching to the G1 collector would give you the benefit that this collector is able to only consider some survivor regions and can leave regions with immortal objects alone.

Comment: Very good points, our NewSize for young generation is very small(600M), I will increase it bigger and it might be helpful.

Comment: The problem is solved after young generation is increased

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I have written [guide](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/07/gc-check-list-for-data-grid-nodes.html) for that topic. It is still very relevant.

Most important thing for CMS garbage collector in sizing. It seems like both your young and old space are undersized.

Old space should be size of your live set (~ heap size after full GC) multiplied by certain factor. Factor is to be found empirically, 1.5 is a good starting point.

Bigger young space is better as long as you are fine with young GC pauses. Young size is also very empiric per application.

`-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=n` and `-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly` are recommended to ensure concurrent cycle timely start. In some situations `-XX:CMSTriggerInterval=p` is also useful.